# Building LINQ query from parameters

Tags: asp.net, linq, lambda

Consider a simple Employee class.

```
Class Employee
{
  public String FirstName {get; set;}
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int Marks {get; set;}
  public String LastName {get; set;}
}
```

So for selecting by LINQ query we can write.

```
var query = Employee.Where(i => i.Id > 2).OrderBy(i => i.Marks);
```

So can we create a function which takes 2 parameter where we can send Id and Marks.
So that i can make a function call and pass parameter what ever i need like.

```
var query = Employee.Where(i => i.Marks > 2).OrderBy(i => i.FirstName);
```

Sample looking function where we can pass any parameter

```
Public String GetQuery(String para1,String para2,......)
{
  var query = Employee.Where(i => i.para1 > 2).OrderBy(i => i.para2); 
  return query;
}
   or

Public String GetQuery(String para1,String para2,......)
{
  String str1=para1...... // with some format included
  String str2=para2...... // with some format included

  var query = Employee.Where(str1).OrderBy(str2); 
  return query;
}
```

The concept is that i want to create a common(generic) query in which i can select values
of any type of parameter passed.

Comment: [Dynamic LINQ][dynamic linq] does exactly what you need. [dynamic linq]: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: So .. you want to take a clean, composable, strongly-typed approach and turn it into a weak, non-composable, string-based approach ...  Why?

Comment: not exactly i just want a generic type. like suppose i want to get a row by column name so in parameter i can pass the context and  column and get required value

Comment: And how does it know what type the column is or what kind of comparison expression you want to do against it ...? You are better off composing a LINQ expression directly given that the caller knows the field, the type and the comparison to make.

Answer (score 0):

A type safe solution could use delegates instead of strings:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> employees = getExampleData();

IEnumerable<Employee> example1 = Query.Employees(employees, Query.UseID, Query.UseMarks);
IEnumerable<Employee> example2 = Query.Employees(employees, Query.UseMarks, Query.UseFirstName);
```

I made a helper class Query to wrap the functionality:

```
static class Query
{
    public static int UseID(Employee employee, int i) { return employee.Id; }
    public static int UseMarks(Employee employee, int i) { return employee.Marks; }
    public static string UseFirstName(Employee employee, string s) { return employee.FirstName; }
    public static string UseLastName(Employee employee, string s) { return employee.LastName; }

    static public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees(IEnumerable<Employee> employees, func_returnInt where, func_returnInt orderby)
    {
        return employees.Where(i => where(i, 0) > 2).OrderBy(i => orderby(i, 0));
    }
    static public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees(IEnumerable<Employee> employees, func_returnInt where, func_returnString orderby)
    {
        return employees.Where(i => where(i, 0) > 2).OrderBy(i => orderby(i, ""));
    }
}

public delegate int func_returnInt(Employee employee, int i);
public delegate string func_returnString(Employee employee, string s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Expression : LambdaExpression.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx.

In my code i have used something similar:

```
private User GetUser(Expression<Func<User, bool>> query)
 {
    User user = context.Users.Where(query).FirstOrDefault();
    if (user == null)
    {
         throw new ProviderException("The supplied user name could not be found.");
    }
    return user;
 }
```

> User user = GetUser(u => u.Marks == 123);
>
> User user = GetUser(u => u.FirstName== "abc");